# Does anyone have a chronological reading order for Warhammer Fantasy?

Tags: suggested-order, warhammer-fantasy

I wanna start reading all the novels but would like to do so going by the actual history/years events are taking place.

Answer (score 1):

#### You won't miss anything by reading stuff out of chronological order

The Warhammer timeline spans about 6,000 years and there are hundreds of novels/novellas written by a dozen or more authors. The storylines weave in and out of each other as well. Most actually have no reference to a date so they just take place at some arbitrary point in time, usually around the time Karl Franz is Emperor.

Absolutely nothing was published in chronological order, so reading books by release date won't really help.

Your best bet is to look over the timeline of world events and search for books which correspond to them. The main events aren't all covered in the books, they would be focused on in the actual Warhammer army books.

[Timeline of the Warhammer fantasy world](http://warhammerfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_the_Warhammer_World)

[Timeline of The End Times](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/The_End_Times)

[Black Library Warhammer Fantasy section](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Warhammer/whfb-qu-re/?page=1&Sort=oldPubDate)

Roughly:

1. you'd want to start with the Elves: [Teclis](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Teclis), [Tyrion](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Tyrion) and [Malekith](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Malekith)
2. then [Nagash](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Nagash)
3. followed by [Sigmar](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Sigmar)
4. and [Neferata](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Neferata).

These storylines will take you from the ancient past up to roughly around the present day and you'll have a decent understanding of the big players.

Then there are buckets of stories which take place around the same time, few have dates and many overlap.

Then you can start [The End Times](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/The_End_Times) where

> the whole world explodes and the bad guys win.

Then you're into the [Age of Sigmar](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Warhammer:_Age_of_Sigmar) and everything is a stupid confusing mess and I recommend you avoid it.

> Everyone you've read about in the fantasy books is dead (or might not be, no one knows and BL won't say).

Comment: It does indeed. But you really won't miss anything by reading them out of order. Sigmars stories were written totally independent of any Elf shenanigans. It's only the later stories around the time of Karl Franz that overlap with humans and elves working together.

Comment: I read it goes the sundering then tyrion and teclis novels because the are relatively young for elves.

Comment: Also where does the black plague, vorag bloody tooth, war of vengeance, age of legend, and The doom of dragonback fit in?

Comment: The timeline link in my answer covers all that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up with:

| Date(s) | Title |
| --- | --- |
| -4500 to -4420 | Aenarion (short story) |
|  | Blood of Aenarion (novel, Prologue Only) |
| -2723 | The Sundering trilogy |
| -2750 | The Great Maw by Laurie Goulding |
| -2005 | The Great Betrayal |
|  | Master of Dragons |
| -1997 | The Curse of the Phoenix Crown (The War of Vengeance) |
| -1968 | Mike Lee’sThe Rise of Nagash trilogy |
|  | Blood of Nagash |
| -1520 | Neferata (Time of Legends) Josh Reynolds |
|  | Masters of Death |
| -1499 | Masters of Stone and Steel |
| -1498 | The Doom of Dragonback |
| -1125 | Orion Trilogy |
| -1094 | Guardians of the Forest |
| -30 | Legend of Sigmar trilogy |
| -30 – 50 | Nagash: The Undying King |
|  | Neferata: Mortarch of Blood |
|  | Hamilcar |
|  | Blacktalon |
| 211 | Sigvald |
| 1111 | Skaven Wars Black Plague Trilogy |
| 1396 | Valkia the Bloody |
| 1797 | Vlad von Carstein Trilogy |
| 1850 | Skaven Pestilens by Josh Reynolds |
| 2010 | Vampire Wars |
| 2173 | Blood of Aenarion (novel portion after the prologue) |
|  | Sword of Caledor & Bane of Malekith |
|  | • Defenders of Ulthuan |
|  | • Sons of Ellyrion |
| 2301 | Sylvaneth |
| 2457 | Van Horstmann |
| 2470 | The Ambassador Chronicles |
| 2482 | The Last Little Bit by Robert Earl |
| 2500 | Golfgag's Revenge by Justin D. Hill |
|  | The Battle of Whitestone by Justin D. Hill |
| 2502 | The Empire Chris Wraight |
| 2515 | Thanquol and Boneripper trilogy |
| 2519-2528 | End of Times (includes the following) |
|  | Empire Army series |
|  | Skarsnik |
|  | Headtaker |
|  | Thorgrim |
|  | Warhammer: Sigmar's Blood |
|  | Archaon Everchosen & Lord of Chaos |
|  | The Return of Negash |
|  | The Fall of Altdorf |
|  | The Curse of Khaine |
|  | Deathblade: A Tale of Malus Darkblade |
|  | The Rise of the Horned Rat |
|  | The Lord of the End Times |

Answer (score -1):

From this [forum](http://www.heresy-online.net/forums/showthread.php?t=115571), a recommended list would be (note that this likely to be opinion-based):

1. Sigmar
2. Nagash
3. Malekith
4. Gotrek & Felix
5. Thanquol
6. Luthor Huss
7. Sword of Vengeance/Sword of Justice Omnibus
8. Witch Hunter Omnibus